# how to audit action download in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, audit

I have problem in alfresco. alfresco provide audit action some properties as modified/added/deleted/move/read.
about [Content Auditing](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Auditing)

But I have audit action about downloading. such as "who do downloading" ,"what time is download"

Comment: Isn't a download a read of the content, so could be audited that way?

Comment: @Gagravarr can i be check download from alfresco ?